# Is there a way to provide multiple keys for tie-breaking when sorting?

Tags: sorting, rust

Is there any built in way to provide multiple keys for tie-breaking in sort? Something like:

`vec.sort_by_key(|k| foo(k), bar(k));`

Where `foo(k)` is the 1st key, and `bar(k)` is the 2nd (tie-breaking) key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a tuple:

```
vec.sort_by_key(|k| (foo(k), bar(k)));
```

Tuples with 0 to 12 fields implement [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html).